# Extract div content with XPath in C#

Tags: c#, .net, html, xml, xpath

I am doing a web scrape and getting back the html. I want to get all the div content from the html with XPath. Here is a snippet of the html:

```
<TD style="background-color:Gainsboro;" class="a83c"><DIV style="word-
wrap:break-word;" class="a83">17173,1</DIV></TD>
<TD style="background-color:Gainsboro;" class="a87c"><DIV style="word-
wrap:break-word;" class="a87">14865,0</DIV></TD>
```

So from this example i would want to extract:
 17173,1     and     14865,0

Please could someone tell me how I would do this using XPath, or if it is easier using Regex?

Thanks.

Comment: If you haven't seen it yet you might want to have a look at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) which lets you treat HTML like XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [Html Agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com) and its [xpath support](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples)